# plain winapi c GUI changing static text background

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am using plain winapi c to create a GUI, I am new to this language and am struggling with something many might think is basic. Could someone please explain to me how I change the background colour for static text because currently is transparent. The code I am using for the text is:

```
 hwndStatic = CreateWindow(TEXT("static"), TEXT(""), 
              WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
              10, 70, 90, 25, hwnd, NULL, g_hinst, NULL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Respond to the [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message in your program and have it return a brush object of the proper color.

I've slightly modified the example from the link:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
    {
        HWND hWnd = (HWND) lParam;
        if (hWnd == hMyStatic)
        {
            HBRUSH hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
            return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the VERY fast reply! I attempted to add this but got the following errors:error #2048: Undeclared identifier 'hMyStatic'.
and error #2168: Operands of '==' have incompatible types 'HWND' and 'int'. It is probably a simple fix but I have just started using this language today and am still learning therefore am struggling and would appreciate your help.

Comment: Sorry for the previous request, it seems to be sort of working now because I changed the hMyStatic.

Comment: @RahulKhosla, I have to admit the example isn't complete - you need to save the brush handle somewhere and delete it at some future point.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you change the drawing of static text controls by handling `WM_GETCTLCOLORSTATIC`.

In that handler, you can change things about the DC, like the text color, background mode, background color, even the font that's selected.

You can also return a handle to a GDI brush (using a cast to get it by the type system).  The control will erase itself first with the brush and then draw the text.

The callback will happen for all static controls that are children of the current window, so you first test to see if it's the child you care about.

For example:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
  HWND hwnd = (HWND) lParam;
  if (hwnd == hwndStatic) {
    HDC hdc = (HDC) wParam;
    ::SetTextColor(hdc, RGB(0xFF, 0, 0));  // set the text to red
    ::SetBkMode(hdc, OPAQUE);
    ::SetBkColor(hdc, RGB(0x00, 0xFF, 0x00));  // set background to green
    HBRUSH hbrBackground = ::GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_WINDOW);  
    return (INT_PTR) hbrBackground;
  }
  return 0;
```

This shows several things you can do.  You probably don't want to do all of them, but it can be educational to see them all in action.

Note that if you create a brush to return, you have to keep track of it and delete it later.  I've avoided this issue by relying on `GetSysColorBrush`.  The system owns those, so you shouldn't delete them.  You can also use `GetStockObject` for system GDI objects that you don't have to manage.  But if you need a custom color, you'll have to use `CreateSolidBrush` and then clean it up.